# Resuming a function after modal is dismissed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm unsure if this is possible to do, so will try to explain it as best as possible. I'm jumping to Ionic 4 after only having experience in Ionic 1, and there are a lot of growing pains involved. In my Ionic 1 apps, I had a lot of functions that included ionic popups, and the popup would be integral to the function completing.

Namely, I am using code similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55041136/5306408

The way my overall code essentially works is that:

- I have a clickable item in a page.
- Clicking on that page initiates a service function.
- The service function calls a URL, and under ideal circumstances returns the data retrieved from that URL to the page.
- However, under some conditions, the user will be required to supply additional information. Ideally, I would like this to happen in a modal: once the user fills out the correct information, the modal is closed, and then the function would continue on to perform its initial goal of calling a URL and returning the data retrieved from it, and returning it to the page in step 1 as intended.

Basically:

Page:

```
... 

pageFunction() void {
    this.someService.someFunction('someURL').then(dataFromTheURL) => {
        //do something with dataFromTheURL
    })
}

...
```

someService:

```
...

async openModal(params) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: someLoginModalPage,
        componentProps: { ... }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
        //need a way to pass dataReturned back to pageFunction()
    });

    return await modal.present();
}

someFunction(url): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve) {
        if (condition is fine and no modal is needed) {
            this.http.get(url, {headers: someHeaderObject}).subscribe(result => {
                resolve(result)
            })
        }
        else {
            //here is the crux of the problem - I need indicatorThatModalHasBeenClosed to come from the modal being closed, not opened
            this.openModal(someParams).then((indicatorThatModalHasBeenClosed) => {

                //do something with indicatorThatModalHasBeenClosed

                this.http.get(url, {headers: someHeaderObject}).subscribe(result => {
                    resolve(result)
                })
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Is this possible to do with Angular modals? I'm having difficulty finding any examples of it, because the code for `openModal` returns the `modal.present()` result, not the data that is passed through `modal.onDidDismiss()`. Ultimately, I want a function (returning a Promise) that opens the modal to resolve with the data that is provided by closing that same modal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've thought of a sort-of workaround: if the modal opens, reject `someFunction` instead of resolving it.

Then, add the properties `dataReturned` and `loginModalActive` to the service that `someFunction` belongs to.

Add `this.loginModalActive = true;` to `openModal`, and

```
this.dataReturned = dataReturned;
this.loginModalActive = false;
```

to the thenable contained `modal.onDidDismiss()` call.

Then, add this function to the service that `someFunction` belongs to:

```
waitForLoginModuleToClose() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const delay = 100;

    interval(delay).subscribe(() => {
      if (!this.loginModalActive) {
        resolve(this.dataReturned);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

In the Page, have `pageFunction()` call itself if the `someService` call is rejected.

It's not quite what I was looking for, but it creates a way for the service to keep track of whether or not the modal should be open, and runs an interval every 100 ms to check if it's open or not. Once it's determined it's not open, then the attempted page function can be tried again.